# npm create-react-app error while creating app in other partition than C

Tags: node.js, create-react-app, npx

I have to partitions of same disk when I try to create the app in the other partition(not the main or home dir) I get some weird error. I'm a novice at this so I have no idea about any of this.

> PS S:\projects>  npx create-react-app my-app npm ERR! code ENOENT npm
> ERR! syscall lstat npm ERR! path C:\Users\niku9\AppData\Roaming\npm
> npm ERR! errno -4058 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or
> directory, lstat 'C:\Users\niku9\AppData\Roaming\npm' npm ERR! enoent
> This is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> C:\Users\niku9\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-08-16T10_07_59_730Z-debug-0.log

this is what I get. any help will be appreciated.

NOTE__ in home C partition it works just fine.

I tried reinstalling nothing improved, and I also checked the automatically install required package this time.

Comment: @AlbertEinstein actually it do.